# Gradle Error while compiling renderscript

Tags: android, android-studio, renderscript

I want to make demo app with help of render script in android studio for photo processing. But when i had build project it give me error of **app:compileDebugRenderscript**
My project specification are as follows.

```
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 19
renderscriptTargetApi 18
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

[image]

Here is the snippet of my renderscript

```
uchar4_attribute_((kernel)) bar(uint32_t x,uint32_t y) {
    uchar4 ret  -((uchar)x,(uchar)y,(uchar)(x+y)(uchar)255)
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show any part of foo.rs? There is an error message above that mentions missing a declaration specifier. Did you skip a return value in the code? Can you try with just a mostly empty source file to get the build right first?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply Please see my updated question

i'm referring youtube  video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kybZnFQh6fE

Comment: uchar4_attribute_ looks suspicious. I am not sure if it is just a bug of stackoverflow code formatting. Please make sure that the uchar4 part is not connected to the __attribute__ part (which uses double underscores around it).

Comment: thanks @StephensHines, it helped me a lot but i'm still struggling with Render script. Thanks for your help